# How to only show portion of x-axis spine on scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, x-axis

I don't want the x-axis spine between (0,0) and (0,4) to display on the scatterplot below.  I still want the distance on the chart, I just don't want the spine to display between those coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(4,10)
y=x
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x=x, y=y)
ax.set_xlim(left=0, right=10)
ax.set_xticks(x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Ideally something like this:

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible([4:])
```

But it yields `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

This hides the entire line:

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
```

I tried [set_position()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/spines_api.html#matplotlib.spines.Spine.set_position):

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('data',4)
```

But I could only get error messages.  If I supplied one argument it said it wasn't enough, but when I supply two it complained about too many:

```
TypeError: Spine.set_position() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What should I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`set_bounds`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/spines_api.html#matplotlib.spines.Spine.set_bounds) methods of the spine. From the docs:

> `set_bounds(low=None, high=None)`
>
> Set the spine bounds.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `low` **float or None, optional**
>
> The lower spine bound. Passing
> None leaves the limit unchanged. The bounds may also be passed as the
> tuple (*low, high*) as the first positional argument.
>
> `high` **float or None, optional**
>
> The higher spine bound. Passing None leaves the limit
> unchanged.

So for your plot, to just change the lower bound to 4, you could use:

```py
ax.spines['bottom'].set_bounds(4)
```

[image]

If you want to also change the upper bound, you could use something like:

```py
ax.spines['bottom'].set_bounds(4, 9)
```